# YouTube Data API - How to get "Saved playlists" via API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to get all of my playlists through YouTube Data API including the public playlist that I have created and playlists that I liked from YouTube.
The playlists that I have liked from YouTube are in separate section which call "Saved playlists".
I'm using

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&channelId={ChannelID}&maxResults=50&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

But I'm getting only the playlist that I have created.
How can I get the "Saved playlists"?

Answer (score -1):

I cannot add a comment, so I'm writing as an answer. (I hope I'm not doing anything against Stackoverflow Terms of Service)

If you would like to retrieve a spesific Playlist, i.e. "Saved Playlist", you should remove the Channel ID from your request and add Playlist ID ...

For example;

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&id={PlaylistID}&maxResults=50&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

I hope it helps.

Comment: This is not helping me. I want to get all of my playlists (created and saved) and by removing the channel ID, I will not get the list of playlists.