# How to get Saved Playlists using Youtube API v3

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to fetch all the playlists(both created and saved) from my youtube channel using youtube v3 api.
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists
But it lists only created playlists. Is there any option to get **saved playlists** also?

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119223/youtube-data-api-how-to-get-saved-playlists-via-api), unfortunately the ability to retrieve "Saved Playlists" is not yet implemented as stated in this [public forum](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6610).

You can create dummy playlist under `Playlists` panel of user's YouTube home page and be able to fetch it using `Playlists:List` API. But NOT yet able to fetch `saved playlists` which are listed under the same list using `Playlists:List` API v3.